# Edit powers activate! Removing Hi/Thanks

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

The format of StackExchange sites in general discourages the sort of letter-format questions common elsewhere. You know what I'm talking about:

> Hi,
>
> I have ${problem}. It has ${details}. Any thoughts?
>
> Thanks in advance, ${username}

Is it OK to use our awesome edit-powers to remove these greetings/signoffs? I say it is OK, as it doesn't affect the meaning of the question, and slots right in next to fixing formatting flubs or interesting spelling.

Comment: It might be nice to include the [MSO link Warner provided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) in any related edits. That's what I've done in the past.  At least then users with clue might check the revision history.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has already been addressed:

[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

I support Kyle's idea of a campaign to discourage the behavior via moderation.  I typically only remove them if I'm already editing for something else.

Comment: This is more about salutation and goodbye messages such as: "Hello techy friends," and "sincerely, lonesome noob"

Comment: That's what he's talking about, @l0c0b0x.

Comment: This is where I am. I don't think its worth editing just for this (unless the flowery language was getting in the way of the question) but I'd certainly tidy it up if I was there anyway.

Comment: It may have been addressed on another site but we don't all read every Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Understandably so, John.  That's why I pointed it out.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it OK to use our awesome edit-powers to remove these greetings/signoffs?

Yes, please do.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if you can be bothered to do so, please *edit* them to:

<del>Hi,</del>

I have ${problem}. It has `${details}`. <del>Any thoughts</del> ${actual question}?

<del>Thanks in advance, ${username}</del>

Answer (score 4):

I've made a number of such edits and will not apologise to anyone for having done so. I also like to point people to the FAQ when it's obvious they haven't bothered to do so.