# New users posting greetings and closings on their questions.

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit powers activate! Removing Hi/Thanks](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876/edit-powers-activate-removing-hi-thanks)

It seems like lately there have been a *lot* more users posting their questions as such:

> Hello!
>
> I have a question. Blah blah blah
>   blah...
>
> Thanks!
>   - My Name

It's been previously established that posting a signature is unnecessary, so I usually remove that. I've also been removing the greetings as well, due to it just decreasing the overall SNR.

I have two questions about this:

1. Is this something I should continue doing or is removing these items too "intrusive"?
2. Can some verbage be addeded to the posting dialogue (perhaps for new users only) that they don't need to post the greeting and closing?

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876/edit-powers-activate-removing-hi-thanks Is where we've talked about this before. Go forth, and edit.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 - Ahh, good to know. Feel free to close/dupe this.

Comment: I think I earned the Strunk and White from these sort of edits.

Comment: @ErikA Personnaly I *really want* to edit out the "any thoughts?" thing, but that's likely just me.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Agreed, I typically edit those out as well if I'm feeling up to it.

Comment: Hi, I agree with this, thanks